# ¿Tengo un problema en mi app de Django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

Tengo un cronómetro en mi modelo de estudio que cuenta con opciones de pausa y reanudación. Estas funciones están funcionando; sin embargo, no se reflejan correctamente en la interfaz visual. Al presionar el botón de pausa, la pausa no se visualiza en la pantalla. He intentado agregar una funcionalidad que, al presionar pausa, aparezca el botón de reanudar. No obstante, para visualizar el botón, debo recargar la página. Lo mismo ocurre con el botón de reanudar;si lo presiono y quiero ver el de pausa nuevamente, es necesario recargar la página para que aparezca el botón de pausa. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema de visualización en tiempo real de las acciones de pausa y reanudación en la interfaz del cronómetro?

views.py:

```
def iniciar_estudio(request, estudio_id):
    estudio = get_object_or_404(Estudio, id_estudio=estudio_id)
    estudio.tiempo_inicio = timezone.now()
    estudio.save()
    return redirect("tareas", id_estudio=estudio_id)


def finalizar_estudio(request, estudio_id):
    estudio = get_object_or_404(Estudio, id_estudio=estudio_id)

    estudio.tiempo_fin = timezone.now()
    estudio.duracion = (
        estudio.tiempo_fin - estudio.tiempo_inicio if estudio.tiempo_inicio else None
    )
    estudio.save()

    return redirect("tareas", id_estudio=estudio_id)


def pausar_estudio(request, estudio_id):
    estudio = get_object_or_404(Estudio, id_estudio=estudio_id)
    print("Pausando estudio...")
    if estudio.tiempo_inicio and not estudio.tiempo_fin and not estudio.pausado:
        estudio.pausado = True
        estudio.tiempo_pausa = timezone.now()
        estudio.save()
    return JsonResponse({})


def reanudar_estudio(request, estudio_id):
    estudio = get_object_or_404(Estudio, id_estudio=estudio_id)
    print("Reanudando estudio...")
    if estudio.tiempo_inicio and not estudio.tiempo_fin and estudio.pausado:
        tiempo_pausado = timezone.now() - estudio.tiempo_pausa
        estudio.tiempo_inicio += tiempo_pausado
        estudio.pausado = False
        estudio.tiempo_pausa = None
        estudio.save()
        return JsonResponse({"tiempo_pausado": int(tiempo_pausado.total_seconds())})
    return JsonResponse({})
```

Este es mi modelo del estudio y donde esta el cronometro:

```
class Estudio(models.Model):
    id_estudio = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    fecha = models.DateField()
    tiempo_inicio = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    tiempo_fin = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    duracion = models.DurationField(null=True, blank=True)
    cronometro = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pausado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    tiempo_pausa = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    maquina = models.ForeignKey(Maquina, related_name="maquina",
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="maquina", )
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, related_name="area",
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, verbose_name="area", )

    def actividades_count(self):
        return self.actividad_set.count()

    def pausar_estudio(self):
        if self.tiempo_inicio and not self.tiempo_fin:
            self.pausado = True
            self.tiempo_pausa = timezone.now()
            # Actualiza la duración cuando se pausa
            self.duracion = self.tiempo_pausa - self.tiempo_inicio
            self.save()

    def reanudar_estudio(self):
        if self.tiempo_inicio and not self.tiempo_fin and self.pausado:
            tiempo_pausado = timezone.now() - self.tiempo_pausa
            self.tiempo_inicio += tiempo_pausado
            self.pausado = False
            self.tiempo_pausa = None
            self.save()
```

Este es mi html donde manejo el cronometro y sus botones:

```
<div class="animated-card">
    <div class="card-content">
        <div class="ag-courses-item_title" style="text-align: center;">
            <h1>Estas son las actividades de tu Estudio de {{ estudio.nombre }}</h1>
            
<div class="ag-courses-item_title">
    <p> Tiempo total del estudio: </p> 
    <span id="cronometro_estudio" data-estudio-id="{{ estudio.id_estudio }}" class="{% if estudio.pausado %}pausado{% endif %}">
        {% if estudio.tiempo_inicio and not estudio.tiempo_fin %}
            {% if estudio.pausado %}
                {{ estudio.tiempo_pausa|duration_format }}
            {% else %}
                {{ estudio.cronometro|duration_format }}
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
      00:00:00
        {% endif %}
    </span>      
</div>
    <!-- Botones para controlar el estudio -->
    <div class="ag-courses-item_date-box">
        {% if not estudio.tiempo_inicio %}
            <a href="{% url 'iniciar_estudio' estudio.id_estudio %}" class="btn btn-primary">Iniciar Estudio</a>
        {% elif not estudio.tiempo_fin %}
            <a href="{% url 'finalizar_estudio' estudio.id_estudio %}" class="btn btn-danger">Finalizar Estudio</a>
            {% if not estudio.pausado %}

                <a href="#" onclick="pausarEstudio('{{ estudio.id_estudio }}')" class="btn btn-warning">Pausar</a>
            {% else %}  
            <a href="#" onclick="reanudarEstudio('{{ estudio.id_estudio }}')" class="btn btn-success">Reanudar</a>
            {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y Este el JavaScript, recalco que ya estoy usando jquery solo que no muestro la importación en el HTML al igual que si estoy llamando el js:

```
function formatoTiempo(segundos) {
    var horas = Math.floor(segundos / 3600);
    var minutos = Math.floor((segundos % 3600) / 60);
    var segundosRestantes = segundos % 60;
    // Devuelve el tiempo formateado como cadena
    return `${horas}:${minutos}:${segundosRestantes}`;
}
setInterval(function () {
    var estudioId = $('#cronometro_estudio').data('estudio-id');
    $.ajax({
        url: `/obtener-tiempo-transcurrido-estudio/${estudioId}/`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#cronometro_estudio').text(formatoTiempo(data.cronometro));
        }
    });
}, 1000);

var estudioInterval;
var tiempoPausado = null;  //
function iniciarCronometroEstudio(estudioId) {
    estudioInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: `/obtener-tiempo-transcurrido-estudio/${estudioId}/`,
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                if (!data.pausado) {
                    tiempoPausado = 0;  // Reinicia el tiempo transcurrido pausado
                    $('#cronometro_estudio').text(formatoTiempo(data.cronometro));
                    $('#cronometro_estudio').removeClass('pausado');
                } else {
                    // Muestra el tiempo transcurrido pausado
                    $('#cronometro_estudio').text(formatoTiempo(tiempoPausado));
                    $('#cronometro_estudio').addClass('pausado');
                    tiempoPausado++;
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);  // Actualiza cada segundo
}
function pausarEstudio(estudioId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/pausar-estudio/${estudioId}/`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function () {
            clearInterval(estudioInterval);
            actualizarBotonesEstudio(estudioId);
            // Guarda el tiempo pausado
            tiempoPausado = $('#cronometro_estudio').text();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Manejar el error de la solicitud AJAX, si es necesario
        }
    });
}
function reanudarEstudio(estudioId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: `/reanudar-estudio/${estudioId}/`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function () {
            iniciarCronometroEstudio(estudioId);
            actualizarBotonesEstudio(estudioId);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Manejar el error de la solicitud AJAX, si es necesario
        }
    });
}
function actualizarBotonesEstudio(estudioId) {
    // Realiza una solicitud AJAX para obtener el estado actual del estudio
    $.ajax({
        url: `/obtener-estado-estudio/${estudioId}/`,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (data) {
            // Actualiza los botones según el estado actual
            if (data.pausado) {
                // Muestra el botón de reanudar y oculta el de pausar
                $('#boton_pausar').hide();
                $('#boton_reanudar').show();
            } else {
                // Muestra el botón de pausar y oculta el de reanudar
                $('#boton_reanudar').hide();
                $('#boton_pausar').show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Django no permite manipular el Dom, por lo que tendras que manejarlo desde Ajax